# Update cached copy of Parse currentUser() in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, caching, parse-platform

I have an ios application, I have implemented Facebook login through Parse. Everything works great in the first trial.

- I can login via Facebook
- My details are stored in the PFUser.currentUser()
- I am able to pull information from the Graph API

But things start to become a problem when I logout (PFUser.logOut()) , and delete the User row from the Parse class and delete the app from Facebook.

The following methods still show that the user is logged in and authenticated.

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
if user.isAuthenticated()
```

I am guessing it is because current user is still using the cached copy of the User. I try executing

```
do
{
  try PFUser.currentUser().fetch()
}
catch{
print("User refreshed")
}
```

But it does not refresh the currentUser() and gives an error. How can I refresh the PFUser.currentUser(), so that it stops saying that the user is logged in and authenticated, even though it's not

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer here,

[Swift & Parse - PFUser currentUser never equals nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216819/swift-parse-pfuser-currentuser-never-equals-nil?rq=1)

I've been struggling with logging out for a little while and I believe I have finally cracked it!

No matter what I did, when I used "PFUser.logOut()" would never set "PFUser.currentUser()" to nil, but it would set "PFUser.currentUser()!.username" to nil...

Because of this I used

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
```

as a global variable to track is a user is logged in.

On my login/first page I added

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
if currentUser != nil {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

}

}
```

and finally on my logout button i used

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "logout" {

    PFUser.logOut() //Log user out

    currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!.username //Reset currentUser variable to nil

}

}
```